# How to create a CakePHP search form?

Tags: cakephp, search, cakephp-3.0

I need to create a very simple search form. My version of CakePHP is 3.0.
I want that search to be associated with a model and to be processed by an action called search in the current controller.
What parameter do I need to pass to `$this->Form->create()` in order to achieve my goal?. Do I have to instantiate a new entity in the controller and pass it to the view?.

This is the search in the view:

```
<div class="search">
    <?= $this->Form->create(null,['action' => 'search']) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('doc_nro', ['required' => true]) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button('Buscar') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

This is my search action:

```
  public function search(){
      $this->isAdmin();
      $dni = $this->request->data['doc_nro'];
      if (!empty($dni)) {
        $query = $this->Recibos->find()
          ->where(['doc_nro =' => $dni]);
        $results = $query->all();
      } 
      if (empty($results)) {
        $this->Flash->error('No se encontraron recibos para ese número de documento');
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'admin']);  
      }
      $this->set('recibos', $results);
    }
```

By passing null I don't get model validation. I'm sure is not the right option but it's a quick dirty one that let me use the form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel: https://github.com/CakeDC/search/tree/3.0

Comment: Or https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search after I've used both I prefer the FoC search plugin for 3.0.

Comment: Thank you both for your input.